# How to share an instance to a CLD user under specific INSTANCE user

Tags: cld

I have an `example.instance_1.2.3.4_22_root` instance in the `default` group, access to instance from CLD server by admin user works fine.

I changed the instance string to user dev `example.instance_1.2.3.4_22_dev` and added it via web interface to the clouds of user jonhdoe, but when i try to access instance from jonhdoe user through the interactive gate with CLI or web terminal i getting error `choosen INSTANCE example.instance_1.2.3.4_22_dev have incorrect GROUP`

How to fix the error?

Init question related to open source infrastructure management system CLD from ClassicDevOps https://github.com/classicdevops/cld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances `example.instance_1.2.3.4_22_root` and `example.instance_1.2.3.4_22_dev` are different and unrelated for the CLD system.

Best practice in this case:

1. Create an instance group like `devaccess` for example with web interface in administration section or with `cld-groupadd` CLI tool and put an instance with `dev` user `example.instance_1 2.3.4_22_dev` into group.
2. Share instance or group to specific user with administration section or direct edit of user instances file.

Also on the instance `example.instance_1.2.3.4_22_dev` in the `authorized_keys` of the dev user, you need to add the main public key of the CLD server from `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`